# HDMI output trimmed on all sides

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, tv

I connected my 900x3c to a Bravia TV via HDMI. Unfortunately, no matter what resolution I choose, the picture is trimmed on all sides (even though I feed it proper 16:9 ratio). I'm not sure, but the picture on the TV doesn't seem to be scaled, pixels seem to be matched precisely. What might be causing that and how do I fix it?

Comment: This can generally be adjusted in software. Which graphics card and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TV is performing [Overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan), consult your tv manual to turn it off, or check if your graphics card supports a "underscan" feature to shrink the display down so it will all fit.

I don't know if you have the same model as the person I saw from a quick google but here is [how they said they fixed it](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1113758).

> On the Bravia I selected HOME > Settings > Setup > Screen Settings >
>   Display Area
>
> It was set to NORMAL I changed it to FULL PIXEL
>
> Changing this to Full Pixel solved the over scan issue and
>   dramatically improved picture quality as I now had a 1 to 1 pixel
>   match meaning that the electronics in the Bravia did not have to
>   calculate any pixel values only simply put each received pixel value
>   into the appropriate pixel location. Basically I was sending a signal
>   to the Bravia that matched the LCD panels Native resolution. This is
>   the best method of driving an LCD.